# How can I get a variable without creating a new instance Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, instance

I'm learning Kotlin and I face some problems.

I want to get a variable from another class but when I call it, there is a new instance of the class who have the variable.

In Java, we're doing this

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeText.text = "another text";
        System.out.println(SomeText.text);
    }
}

class SomeText {
    public static String text = "My Text";
}
```

And the result is "another text".

But in Kotlin if I'm using this :

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SomeText().text = "Another text"
    println(SomeText().text)
}

class SomeText{
    var text = "My Text"
}
```

The result is "My Text".

Do you know how can I get the variable and edit it without creating a new instance ?
I tried the `SomeText::text` but it return a KMutableProperty1 instead of a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate `static` in Kotlin by using [companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects). So the following in Java

```java
class SomeText {
    public static String text = "My Text";
}
```

will be in Kotlin

```kotlin
class SomeText {
    companion object {
        var text = "My Text"
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to update your `main`:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SomeText.text = "Another text"
    println(SomeText.text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin does not have static methods and class, but instead you can use companion object:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SomeText.text = "Another text"
    println(SomeText.text)
}

class SomeText {
    companion object {
      var text = "My Text"   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !